# How to generate snapshot after all life cycle methods have called in React Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

snapshot file has created before `componentDidMount()` is being called. In my situation, I fetch data from server inside the `componentDidMount()`. Based on the results, I draw the table. But in my test case, it doesn't show those *received mock results*.

### Test file

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { fakeRequestLibrary } from '../../../__mocks__/fakeRequestLibrary';
import ReportAsTableView from '../../../components/reports/common/ReportAsTableView';

const FAKE_RESPONSE = {
    dataSets: [
        {
            metadata: {
                columns: [
                    {
                        name: "username",
                        label: "username"
                    },
                    {
                        name: "date_created",
                        label: "date_created"
                    }
                ]
            },
            rows: [
                {
                    date_created: "2010-04-26T13:25:00.000+0530",
                    username: "daemon"
                },
                {
                    date_created: "2017-06-08T21:37:18.000+0530",
                    username: "clerk"
                },
                {
                    date_created: "2017-07-08T21:37:18.000+0530",
                    username: "nurse"
                },
                {
                    date_created: "2017-07-08T21:37:19.000+0530",
                    username: "doctor"
                },
                {
                    date_created: "2017-07-08T21:37:18.000+0530",
                    username: "sysadmin"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

};

describe('<ReportAsTableView /> ', () => {
    it('renders correctly with success data received from server', () => {
        const params = {
            "startDate": "2017-05-05",
            "endDate": "2017-10-05"
        };


        var rendered = renderer.create(
            <ReportAsTableView reportUUID="e451ae04-4881-11e7-a919-92ebcb67fe33"
                reportParameters={params}
                fetchData={fakeRequestLibrary('openmrs-fake-server.org', {}, true, FAKE_RESPONSE)} />
        );

        expect(rendered.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

### Targeted component class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ApiHelper } from '../../../helpers/apiHelper';
import * as ReportConstants from '../../../helpers/ReportConstants';
import ReactDataGrid from 'react-data-grid';
import DataNotFound from './DataNotFound';
import moment from 'moment';
import './ReportAsTableView.css';


class ReportAsTableView extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super();
        this.state = {
            report: {
                definition: {
                    name: ''
                }
            },
            reportColumnNames: Array(),
            reportRowData: Array()
        };
        this.resolveResponse = this.resolveResponse.bind(this);
        this.rowGetter = this.rowGetter.bind(this);
        this.init = this.init.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.init(this.props.reportParameters);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.init(nextProps.reportParameters);
    }

    init(params) {

        if(this.props.fetchData != null){
            //Test Path
            this.props.fetchData
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('>>>>>'+JSON.stringify(response.body));
                this.resolveResponse(response.body);
            });
        }else{
            new ApiHelper().post(ReportConstants.REPORT_REQUEST + this.props.reportUUID, params)
            .then((response) => {
                this.resolveResponse(response);
            });
        }
    }

    resolveResponse(data) {
        this.setState({ report: data });
        this.setState({ reportColumnNames: data.dataSets[0].metadata.columns });
        this.setState({ reportRowData: data.dataSets[0].rows });
    }

    // ... there are some other methods as well


    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ border: '1px solid black' }}>

                {this.getColumns().length > 0 ? (

                    <ReactDataGrid
                        columns={this.getColumns()}
                        rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
                        rowsCount={this.state.reportRowData.length} />
                ) : (
                    <DataNotFound componentName="Report Table"/>
                )}

            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default ReportAsTableView;
```

### Snapshot file

```
// Jest Snapshot v1,

exports[`<ReportAsTableView />  renders correctly with success data received from server 1`] = `
<div
  style={
    Object {
      "border": "1px solid black",
    }
  }
>
  <div
    className="NotFoundWrapper"
  >
    <div
      className="attentionSign"
    >
      <img
        src="./warning.png"
        width="300"
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      No Data found 
      <span>
        for 
        Report Table
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;
```

**Update:**

### fakeRequestLibrary

```
import Response from 'http-response-object';

export const fakeRequestLibrary = (requestUrl, requestOptions, shouldPass = true, responseData = null) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (shouldPass) {
      resolve(new Response(200, {}, responseData || { message: `You called ${requestUrl}` }, requestUrl));
    } else {
      reject(new Response(404, {}, responseData || { message: `The page at  ${requestUrl} was not found` }, requestUrl));
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you post the code of fakeRequestLibrary please ?

Comment: @GabrielDiez I have added the fakeRequestLibrary as well :)

Comment: I think you have this issue because fakeRequestLibrary is asynchronous. You should try to pass fake data to your component and then render them and not try to reproduce an API Call. Don't forget you are testing the render and not the whole component

Comment: Here is my project. Can you construct an answer? [Repository](https://github.com/JudeNiroshan/openmrs-owa-built-in-reports)

Comment: this.props.fetchData is suppose to be what ? Data Fetched previously ?

Comment: It has used to get the mock http end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing an http end point what you can do for fix your problem is changing your init method and passing the data if no data are passed fetch them. Like this

```
init(params) {

    if(this.props.fetchData != null){
            this.resolveResponse(this.props.fetchData);
    }else{
        new ApiHelper().post(ReportConstants.REPORT_REQUEST + this.props.reportUUID, params)
        .then((response) => {
            this.resolveResponse(response);
        });
    }
}
```

Then in your test you will have

```
    var rendered = renderer.create(
        <ReportAsTableView reportUUID="e451ae04-4881-11e7-a919-92ebcb67fe33"
            reportParameters={params}
            fetchData={FAKE_RESPONSE} />
    );

    expect(rendered.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for my own project. It might also work for this question as well, but I haven't tested it. Add an `await wait();` statement to wait for the async function in `componentDidMount` to complete.

```js
const wait = async () => 'foo'; // a dummy function to simulate waiting

describe('<ReportAsTableView /> ', async () => {
  it('renders correctly with success data received from server', async () => {
    const params = {
      startDate: '2017-05-05',
      endDate: '2017-10-05',
    };

    var rendered = renderer.create(
      <ReportAsTableView
        reportUUID="e451ae04-4881-11e7-a919-92ebcb67fe33"
        reportParameters={params}
        fetchData={fakeRequestLibrary(
          'openmrs-fake-server.org',
          {},
          true,
          FAKE_RESPONSE,
        )}
      />,
    );

    await wait(); // wait for <ReportAsTableView> to finish async data fetch in componentDidMount()

    expect(rendered.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot(); // shall render the component AFTER componentDidMount() is called
  });
});
```